# I am struggling with PHP number formatting

Tags: php, number-formatting

I am extremely new to PHP, and I am having some issues with the number_format() function.

I am performing a calculation which is, correctly, returning this result: 6215.
However, I want this value to be displayed/echoed as 62.15. I have played around with the number_format() function to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 potential tasks here.

1.) You want to change your number (divide by 100)

```
<?php
  $number = 6215;
  $number = $number / 100;
  echo $number;
?>
Renders as 62.15
```

2.) You may want additional formatting to make a "pretty" number

From the docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

```
// Function signature syntax
number_format(
    float $num,
    int $decimals = 0,
    ?string $decimal_separator = ".",
    ?string $thousands_separator = ","
)

<?php
  $number = 1006215.56;
  $pretty_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
  echo $pretty_number;
?>
Renders as 1,006,215.56
```

Answer (score 0):

This was directly pulled from the php.net documentation, which I think is really great.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

```
<?php

$number = 1234.56;

// english notation (default)
$english_format_number = number_format($number);
// 1,235

// French notation
$nombre_format_francais = number_format($number, 2, ',', ' ');
// 1 234,56

$number = 1234.5678;

// english notation without thousands separator
$english_format_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
// 1234.57

?>
```